# Check if elements in a list equal to the sum value of the list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out a more pythonic way of accepting a list and enumerating through the list, checking whether the sum of a sequence of elements == to the sum of the whole list, if so, it will create a return a sub list.

Note: A solution for checking any combination of elements would be interesting too.

For example:

```
example1 = [8, 9, 10, 10, 10, -20]
```

**Output** = [8, 9, 10]

```
example2 = [-15, 6, 8, 2, 10, 10, -5]
```

**Output** = [6, 8, 2]

Comment: what do you mean by "few elements"? In sequence or any combinations? NB it is a bad habit to shadow build-it, etc names, use `l`, `lst`, `list_`, ...

Comment: @cards any combination of values, also good point on the variable names, I'll change it

Comment: @cards seeing a solution to a sequence of numbers would be interesting too

Comment: Another way to look at the logic would be to remove elements from the list that sum to 0. For example, in the first example, you remove 10, 10, and -20. In the second example, you remove -15, -5, 10, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over all combinations of `list`:

```
import itertools


def calc_sum(lst):
    res = []
    lst_sum = sum(lst)
    for L in range(1, len(lst)):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(lst, L):
            if sum(subset) == lst_sum:
                res.append(subset)
    print(set(res))


for item in ([8, 9, 10, 10, 10, -20], [-15, 6, 8, 2, 10, 10, -5]):
    calc_sum(item)
```

Edit: You just need to iterate for each list item to the end:

```
def calc_sum(lst):
    len_lst = len(lst)
    lst_sum = sum(lst)
    for i in range(0, len_lst):
        for j in range(i, len_lst):
            _subList = lst[i:j]
            if sum(_subList) == lst_sum:
                print(_subList)
```

Out:

```
{(8, 9, 10)}
{(6, 8, 2), (6, 10)}
```

Comment: How would this be done with a sequence of numbers? rather than any combination?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pattern](http://#%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from `itertools` to find all subsets of a list. Using this pattern, a solution would be:

```
import itertools


# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)))
    # return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s) + 1))


def find_subsets(ll: list):
    ll_sum = sum(ll)
    return set([s for s in powerset(ll) if sum(s) == ll_sum])


print(find_subsets([-15, 6, 8, 2, 10, 10, -5]))

# gives: [(6, 10), (6, 8, 2)]
```

Note that in the final result list there will be some double entries that eventually need to be filtered out. Also, the total list is a solution.

Comment: How would this be done with a sequence of numbers? rather than any combination?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by a 'sequence of numbers' and what the expected output would be for an example

Comment: Your current code prints out any combination of numbers that add up to the sum of the list. Only accepting sequences would result in :  `[8, 9, 10, 10, 10, -20] = [8, 9, 10]`  and `[8, 9, -20, 10, 10, -20, 9] = [ ]`

Comment: I added a cast from list to set so that there are no double entries anymore (although, there are identical subsets leading to the same sum ...). Furthermore, I excluded the whole list as a solution (which is in fact a solution to the problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for consecutive sequences , you can use the accumulate() function (from itertools) to get cumulative sums and check if any difference between these sequential sums is equal to the total of the list.  This will allow you to use a set to accelerate the process and get a near O(n) time complexity:

```
from itertools import accumulate
def seqSum(L):
   s = sum(L)
   a = [0,*accumulate(L)]  # sequential totals
   sa = set(a)             # accelerate matching using a set
   return  [ L[i:i+a[i+1:].index(v+s)+1] for i,v in enumerate(a)
             if v+s in sa and v+s in a[i+1:(None,-1)[i<1]]]
```

Output:

```
print(seqSum([8, 9, 10, 10, 10, -20]))    # [[8, 9, 10]]

print(seqSum([-15, 6, 8, 2, 10, 10, -5])) # [[6, 8, 2]]

print(seqSum([-15, 6, 8, 2, 10, -4, 10, 4, -5]))
# [[6, 8, 2], [8, 2, 10, -4], [10, -4, 10]]
```

*Note that this will not find overlapping sequences that begin on the same element, so only one sequence (the shortest) can be obtained for each position in the list*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood what you mean by *only sequences*:

```
import itertools


# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)))


def is_sequence(iterable):
    """ checks if iterable is a sequence of number such as [5, 6, 7], irrespective of the order
    Uses the fact that sum([a, a+1, a+2, ..., a+n]) = n*(n+1)/2 + a*(n + 1)
    """
    n = len(iterable) - 1
    m = min(iterable)
    return max(iterable) - m == n and sum(iterable) == n*(n+1)/2 + m*(n + 1)


def find_subsets(ll: list, only_sequences=False):
    ll_sum = sum(ll)
    if only_sequences is True:
        return set([s for s in powerset(ll) if sum(s) == ll_sum and is_sequence(s)])
    else:
        return set([s for s in powerset(ll) if sum(s) == ll_sum])


print(find_subsets([6, 8, 9, 10, 10, -19], False))  # (6, 8, 9)
print(find_subsets([6, 8, 9, 10, 10, -19], True))   # empty set
print(find_subsets([7, 8, 9, 10, 10, -20], True))   # (7, 8, 9)
```